# Meteor - How to redirect to external urls(eg. http://www.google.com) using Flowrouter

Tags: meteor, flow-router, external-url

I am trying payment gateway and i want to redirect user to payment url provided by the quickwallet? Any solution ? 
Something like FlowRouter.go(url);
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlowRouter does not support redirect to an external url, you need to use `window.location.href` to redirect to external route:

```
window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
```